# Error: blscrapeR cannot extract data from online by text/plain length unknown error in r

Tags: r

When I introduced `blscrapeR` for library, and try to use `get_bls_county()` to get data from online. I run into the following error:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmQ40.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sh8il.png)

I got 0 observations. I think there is a problem with text reading, but I cannot fix it.

Comment: Do not post images. Consoles are in text format, Copy and paste your code and problem.

Comment: I figure out the problem by myself. This problem exists in a lot of my friends' computers. Actually, it is due to the language environment of the computer. When using the Chinese operating system, it is not working. But using English it will work out fine.